# How to pack large structure with byte string in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and am looking for guidance in packing a byte string into a python ctypes class that corresponds to a C structure with ~100 fields. Is there another way besides defining a very large (and error prone) format string for use with pack()? This task is very easy in C with memcpy(). My goal for this task is to display and analyze the fields.

Thank you.

Comment: Show what you've tried and a sample of what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

[`ctypes.Structure` subclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) let you define the same structure in Python, with a memory layout that could be `memcpy`-ed into via a `memoryview`. It's more typing, but it's also far less error-prone than long `struct` format strings.

Once defined, the `memcpy` equivalent in Python would be:

```
struct = MyStructure()

memoryview(struct).cast('B')[:] = mybytes
```

`memoryview(struct)` uses the buffer protocol to create a view of the underlying raw memory, `.cast('B')` returns a new view of the complicated structure as raw bytes, then `[:]` is used to slice assign from a bytes-like object.

There are also alternate constructors that can copy directly from a buffer if you have one available at construction time, e.g.:

```
struct = MyStructure.from_buffer_copy(mybytes)
```

or if `mybytes` is a mutable `bytearray` (or some other mutable bytes-like object) you can actually make a structure backed by it directly:

```
# struct is now backed by mybytearray; changing it will change mybytearray
struct = MyStructure.from_buffer(mybytearray)
```